# Malloc error incorrect checksum for freed object

Tags: objective-c, macos, malloc

I have written a objective-c wifi library and a c wrapper around it to call from my c++ code using corewlan framework.I have setup timers and on expiry of the timer i call scanwifi function of the library which gives details of all the wifi network details.The program keeps crashing by giving malloc error incorrect check sum for freed object. The crash is not consistent,keeps appearing a random places. I tried guard malloc to find the memory bug, left the program running for more than 10 hours but it didn't crash. as soon as i removed guard malloc and executed the program and boom there was the crash. Can anyone please tell ways to catch this memory bug
Thanks

Comment: Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq for better understanding on how you should ask a question. You must show us what you have done so far in order to get help. So be specific with your question and add necessary snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory management errors can be particularly difficult to track down; without seeing code it's hard to say.

You mentioned GuardMalloc—have you tried enabling other [Diagnostics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html)?

- Scribble
- Guard Edges
- Guard Malloc
- Zombie Objects

This can help debugging by making your code crash more predictably—hopefully closer to the source of the error.

(In Xcode 4.4.1, these are set via "Product"->"Edit scheme"->"Run"->"Diagnostics".)